# Filter more than one column with JavaScript table filter

Tags: javascript

Using the table filter from the [W3C](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp) site, how do you modify the search `td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];`, to look at more than just the first column `[0]` that its currently built to filter by?

```
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");


  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0]; -Here replace 0 with a variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's already a loop to loop over rows (trs). So I've just added another loop after it to loop over the columns (tds).

The second for loop goes over *all* the columns in each row. It can be modified to suit OP's requirements.

Try this (for all columns):

```
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");


    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {

        tds = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
        var found = false;      //----------used to see if any col returns a positiv match
        //---second loop that goes over all tds in a tr ---can be modified as required to go over only certain tds
        for (j = 0; j < tds.length; j++){
             td = tds[j];
             if (td) {
                  if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                  found = true;
                  break;
              }
           }
      }

    if(found)
        tr[i].style.display = "";
    else
        tr[i].style.display = "none";

     }
    }
```

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you have done to fix the issue.